# Change body class depending on current option in select list

Tags: javascript

Without using jQuery, how can I change the body class based on the currently selected option in a select list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("dropDownListID");
var optnValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
if(optnvalue == "something")
  document.body.className = "newClass";
else
  document.body.className = "otherClass";
```

Idea is to get the option value and then based on the value you get change the class of the body tag

**NOTE**
This will have text of the option tag
i.e., `<option value="1">something</option>`
So `ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text` will give you `something` and
`ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value` will give you `1`